# Never had the chance to find a crash log file

Tags: rendering, interface, error, windows

Since my start with Blender, and including today, I need to find out why Blender is crashing. Whenever I get a crash and google it, I go through they same process: I locate the temp folder, but nothing is there.

Is it actually possible that Blender does not create a crash log?

Thank you

Comment: See the [Blender docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/troubleshooting/crash.html#crash-log) for details about crash logs.